# Can't send parameters in POST request in AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I have playing with AFNetworking. In their example here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.0/ there is

`NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};`

When i print this variable to console, it shows as

```
{
    foo = bar;
}
```

and everything works fine. If i pass to this method my NSMutableDictionary, which contains

```
{
    apikey = 123;
    stationId = 6;
}
```

I get this exception: `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7bf54c60 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

I really dont know where is the problem. (I am beginner in Objective C and AFNetworking, so sorry about my unknowledgement :))

Here is full code:

```
- (void) POST:(NSString *) url withData:(NSMutableDictionary *) jsonData
{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

NSString *fullUrl = [self.baseUrl stringByAppendingString:url];

[jsonData setValue:self.apiKey forKey:@"apikey"];

NSLog(@"%@", [jsonData description]);
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"stationId": @"6", @"apikey" : @"fdfd"};
NSLog(@"%@", [parameters description]);

[manager POST:fullUrl parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Please show the code that actually makes the `AFNetworking` call

Comment: Now i've found that if I have as apikey string @"123" it is the error and apikey string @"abc" is ok... and this is the source of the error but i cant't understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with AFNetworking this usually means you are getting a non-JSON response back. This can be something like a 403 or just malformed JSON. Are you looking at the traffic coming back?

Comment: this was right answer, I thought it was my bad JSON, but it was response JSON :) thank you